# In rosyln, how to get the syntaxnode with a location given?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am currently learning roslyn source generator. What I intend to make is a source generator that automatically implements interfaces property member when a type interit interface but corresponding members are not implemented. The automaticlly implemented members will be autoproperty by default.

What I have done so far:

```
    [Generator]
    public class AutoImplementInterfaceGenerator : ISourceGenerator {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context) {
            context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxContextReceiver());
            
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context) {
            List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>();
            foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in context.Compilation.GetDeclarationDiagnostics()) {
                if (diagnostic.Id == "CS0535" && !Locations.Contains(diagnostic.Location)) {
                    Locations.Add(diagnostic.Location);
                }
            }
            foreach (Location location in Locations) {
                SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPositionAsync()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am stuck on finding the `SyntaxNode` of where [Compiler Error CS0535](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0535?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0535)) occur, which is represented by `Diagnostic.Location`(See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.location?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0)). An alternative I found was `SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPositionAsync`(See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.findsymbols.symbolfinder.findsymbolatpositionasync?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_FindSymbols_SymbolFinder_FindSymbolAtPositionAsync_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Document_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)) method, however it requires a `Document`or `Workspace`. I have no idea about how to get a instance of that within APIs related to source generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the location type has a reference to the syntax tree the location comes from. You need to get the "Root" node (the first node in the tree) and then call `FindNode` on the root to get the nearest child node at the given span. Should look something like this:

```cs
foreach (Location location in Locations) {
    SyntaxNode rootNode = location.SourceTree.GetRoot();
    SyntaxNode nodeAtLocation = rootNode.FindNode(location.SourceSpan);
}
```